# How can I calculate values from several input fields in an IONIC form and output them in the form?

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, calculation

I have an order form in which a route (A, B, C) and the number of vehicles (Car A, B, C) should be selected. The prices for the different vehicles and routes are shown in the table. Now I would like to calculate and display a price when selecting the vehicle quantity (event onChange). How can I display an additional value in the form?

Thanks in advance.

```
html - File

...
    <ion-item>  
          <ion-label floating>Tour</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="tourModel" (ionChange)="onChange(tourModel)">
              <ion-option value="0">no</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="1">Route A</ion-option> 
              <ion-option value="2">Route B</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="3">Route C</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>

        Car A <select [(ngModel)]="carAmodel" (onChange)="onChgS6(carAmodel)">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
            </select>  if { route === A } {{ carAmodel * priceA }} => something like that
        Car B <select>
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
            </select> {{ priceCarB }}
       Car C <select>
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
            </select>  {{ priceCarC }}
      ......

   .ts File

   onChange(carAmodel) {
       if ( carAmodel === "1" )
          { priceA = 

    }



#######################
   Pricetable

   Route/CarOption        A        B        C
   Route A                42       60       75
   Route B                48       70       85
   Route C                60       80      100

   priceTable = ['Route A'][42,60,75],
                ['Route B'][48,70,85],
                ['Route C'][60,80,100]

   Don't know how to define this Array.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if { route === A } {{ carAmodel * priceA }}
```

Can be done using [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

```
<span *ngIf="route === A"> {{carModel * priceA}} </span>
```

The price table can be structured in many ways, one example can be:

```
const priceTable = {
    'Route A' : {
        A: 42,
        B: 60,
        C: 75
    },
    ....
}
```

Which can be consumed like:

```
<span *ngIf="route === A"> {{priceTable['Route A'][carModel]}} </span>
```

It is worth looking at `*ngSwitchCase` and also you can create a PriceComponent that takes a route and car as `@Input`

```
<app-price-display [route]="selectedRoute" [car]="selectedCar"></app-price-display>
```

In this case, all price calculation logic and display logic becomes local to the component.

Comment: Ok, it works so far. But the Output isn't as expected for select 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works not at all selects. Output of select 2 and 3 ist Nan €.

Here is my html code

```
    <ion-item>  
      <ion-label floating>route</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="route"  (ionChange)="onChange(route)"> 
          <ion-option value="0">no</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="1" >route a</ion-option> 
          <ion-option value="2">route b</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="3">route c</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <div [hidden]="!hideMe"  >



    <pre>
    6er <select [(ngModel)]="S6" name="S6">
          <option selected>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>  <span *ngIf="route != 0">{{ priceTable[1][6] * S6 }} €</span>
    8er <select [(ngModel)]="S8" name="S8" ng-init="S8===0">
          <option selected>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select> {{ priceTable[1][8] * S8}} €
   10er <select [(ngModel)]="S10" name="S10">
          <option selected>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select> <span *ngIf="route != 0">{{ priceTable[1][10] * S10}} €</span>
     <br>
    </pre>

    </div>
  </ion-card-content>
```

Comment: Will need the typescript file as well to comment on this.